# Reading file contents line-by-line while using each iteration in another script/function for manipulation [Python/Threading]

Tags: python, multithreading, function, stdout, race-condition

I'm using (2) .py scripts. read.py reads the content of a file line-by-line, and  process.py needs to access the values from read.py for manipulation. How do I access each read-line iteration from read.py, and use the value in process.py for manipulation?

**read.py**

```
def read_file_line():
    with open('data_file.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            lineValue = line
            lineStripValue = lineValue.rstrip("\n")
            formattedLine = lineStripValue
            print formattedLine
```

**process.py**

```
def process_data():
    for line in read_file_line()
    lineValue = lineData
    newLineValue = str('text') + lineValue
    print newLineValue
```

First, I'm wondering if the read.py has the expanded functionality that is required, and if a loop is needed for the script-script-function communication. It does read file contents correctly and without loading the entire file(s) into memory as they are 50GB.

Secondly, what are generally schema to having one scripts functions and return values accessible in another script, or use functions as parameters in other functions?

**Example**

My data_file has keys:

```
0004672
00054356-346436
7437865663-7363
23562-3735-9994
```

Reading the contents of data_file line-by-line while having each line stored in a variable that can be accessed from another script functi
on. If the manipulation was to factor each key by X, and return the result. read.py would iterate over the data_file while simultaneously passing each iterative value into another script's function for processing. I'm doing a lot of work that requires different functions and scripts to be used in other scripts and functions, and want to ensure any technique standards for this kind of communication. Would threading be needed as implementation if scripts are running simultaneously?

**Output**
    factorkey = string value

```
factorkey0004672
factorkey00054356-346436
factorkey7437865663-7363
factorkey23562-3735-9994
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you printing the lines to `stdout` in the `read_file_line.py` but you actually want to return the lines to further work with it. So, why not use a generator to get the lines line-by-line?

E.g.,

### read.py

```
def read_file_line(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            lineValue = line
            lineStripValue = lineValue.rstrip("\n")
            formattedLine = lineStripValue
            yield formattedLine
```

### process.py

```
from read import read_file_line

def process_data(path):
    for line in read_file_line(path):
        lineValue = lineData
        newLineValue = str('text') + lineValue
    print newLineValue

process_data('./data_file.txt')
```